# Why do properties of a SPECIFIC div element spread to other separate div elements?

Tags: html, css

I made a small practice website.
I came up with a problem that is kind of frustrating.

I made a div as follows:

```
<div class="work-process">

        <div class="container" align="center">

            <div class="col-md-12">

                <p class="takeaway"> Learn about our creative & unique work process </p>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 btn-column">

                <a href="aboutus.html">

                    <div class="btn btn-workp">

                        <p class="button-text"> Learn More </p>

                    </div>

                </a>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

I set the background image of this div, but instead of just setting this small div section, it also made the previous div have the same background-image. In mobile format, the previous div no longer shares the image but this div ("work-process") does and is in the middle overlapping the previous div. When I inspected the element in Chrome, "work-process" seems to span across the ENTIRE page. Why is this?

The CSS:

```
h1, h2, h3{
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
p{
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
a{
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
.top-infobar{
    background-color: #1A1C27;
}
.top-infobar p{
    color: grey;
    font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
    padding-right: 2%;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-top: 4px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.top-infobar p:hover{
    color: white;
}
.navbar{
    margin-bottom: 0;
     border-radius: 0
}
.navbar-default a{
    color: #2164FF;
}
#external_links a{
    font-size: 110%;
}
.icon-bar{
    background-color: white;
}
/* Jumbotron */
.humbotron{
    background-image: url("images/nyc.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: 56% 25%;
    background-attachment: fixed;

}
.humbotron h1{
    margin-top: 15%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 500%;
    display:inline-block;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding-right: 5%;
    padding-left: 5%;
}

.hook p{
    color: white;
    font-size: 150%;
    margin-top: 1%;
}
.hook2 p{
    color: white;
    font-size: 150%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .humbotron h1{
        font-size: 350%;
    }

}
.lm-row{
    margin-top: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;

}
.button{
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
}
.lm-row a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 100%;
}
.button:hover{
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.lm-row a:hover{
    color: black;
}

/* Second page */
.desc-page{
    height:100vh; 
}
.header2{
    margin-top: 2%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.header-underline{
    border-color: #acadad;
    max-width: 50%;
}
#laptop-img-sec{
    margin-top: 5%;
}
.laptopimg img{
    max-width: 100%;
}
.all-descs{
    height: 100%;
}
#images-folder{
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}
.all-descs:hover #circle{
    background-color: #90C3D4;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}
.all-descs{
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
.complimentary-desc h3{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
/* Work Process advert */
.work-process{
    background-image: url('images/paint.jpg');
    padding-bottom: 5%;
}
.takeaway{
    font-size: 200%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    color: white;
}
.btn-column{
    margin-top: 3%;
}
.btn-workp {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
  border: solid #ffffff 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-workp:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}
```

All HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<!-- Head -->
<head>
    <meta charset="uft-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title> Coherent </title>

        <!-- JQuery -->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> 
        <!-- Bootstrap -->

            <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


        <!-- CSS -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">

        <!-- Raleway font -->
            <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

        <!-- Other font -->

        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
<!-- End of Head -->

<body>
    <div class="top-infobar">

         <p> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"> </span>(647)-550-3998</p>

         <p> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"> </span> info@coherent.ca </p>

    </div>

    <!-- Navigation Bar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">

            <div class="navbar-header">

                <a href="home.html" class="navbar-brand"> Coherent</a>

                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">

                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation </span>

                <div id="collapse-button">

                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

                <ul id="external_links" class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <li><a href="home.html">Home </a></li>

                    <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us </a></li>

                    <li><a href="services.html">Services </a></li>

                    <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us </a></li>

                </ul>

            </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Homemade Jumbotron -->
    <div class="humbotron col-md-12">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="header col-md-12" align="center" id="main_header">

                    <h1> Coherent </h1> 

                </div>


                <div class="hook col-md-12" align="center" id="first_hook">

                    <p> Hello from the other side </p>

                </div>

                <div class="hook2 col-md-12" align="center" id="second_hook">

                    <p> To tell u I'm sorry </p>

                </div>

                <div class="lm-row col-md-12" align="center">

                    <a href="services.html" id="lm-link" class="button">Learn More</a>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="desc-page col-md-12">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="header2 col-md-12" align="center">

                    <h2 style="font-size: 300%"> <strong> What you get </strong> with Coherent </h2>
                    <hr class="header-underline">

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

            <div class="row" id="laptop-img-sec">

                <div class="laptopimg col-md-6">

                    <img src="images/adele.png" align="center">

                </div>

                <div class="img-qualities col-md-6">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="all-descs col-md-12">

                            <img id="images-folder" src="images/skilled-team.png">  

                            <div class="complimentary-desc">

                                <h3> A <strong> skilled </strong> and <strong> reliable </strong> team </h3>

                                <p> With Coherent, you get a reliable, professional, and experienced team to tend to your graphic design and social media needs </p>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="all-descs col-md-12">

                                <img id="images-folder" src="images/professional-services.png">

                            <div class="complimentary-desc">

                                <h3> <strong> Professional </strong> services </h3>

                                <p> You can be assured a professional job and final finish. Take a seat, and let the experts handle this </p>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="all-descs col-md-12">

                            <img id="images-folder" src="images/fast-and-efficient.png">

                            <div class="complimentary-desc">

                                <h3> <strong> Fast </strong> and <strong> Efficient </strong> services </h3>

                                <p> When you have made an order, we ensure that you are our top priority until its finished. </p>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

    </div>

    <div class="work-process">

        <div class="container" align="center">

            <div class="col-md-12">

                <p class="takeaway"> Learn about our creative & unique work process </p>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 btn-column">

                <a href="aboutus.html">

                    <div class="btn btn-workp">

                        <p class="button-text"> Learn More </p>

                    </div>

                </a>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: side note: you are passing repeated `id` to images instead of a `class`

Comment: not sure I understand your question. Div's are wrappers. if you don't specify size. all divs will take the size of whatever child has a size. So 5 nested divs and one 400x400 image.. all divs will be 400x400

Comment: Tell me what is missing in this https://jsfiddle.net/tirthrajbarot/1zLhywr1/2/

Comment: @warkentien2 yes I know but I'm talking about the completely separate enclosed div before this one.

Comment: @TirthrajBarot `clear: both` really fixed it. If you were to make the page smaller though(by dragging the side inwards), theres an overflow of the previous div onto this one. Also, if you were to call inspect element, for example, it would make the div `work-process` move up onto the div `desc-page`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because your other divs are floating, hence `work-process` background takes up whole page.

To fix this, disallow any floating elements besides the div `work-process`, Add below css:

```
.work-process{
clear: both;
}
```

Comment: That worked surprisingly well! Another problem still persists. Some of the other div has overlapped on this one. Just a bit.. Can you help me with that. Thanks btw

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to show the behavior? or add a new question with new issue?

Comment: @JohnDoe I think you should change `.desc-page {
    height: auto; }` instead of specifying fixed height. Since your elements are floating and have relative positions, it could cause issue